# Data not loading to detail view controller when first row selected

Tags: objective-c, ios, subview

When I launch the app in question I load up a table from an array derived from a plist.  In didSelectRowAtIndexPath I assign values from the array to sub views in detail view controller and then push the detail view controller onto the stack, but when running the app, **the first time** I select any row from the table, data from the array does not appear in my detail view controller's subviews/fields.  I then click back to the table view, re-select the row and the data then loads in the detail view controller.

In the table view controller didSelectRowAtIndexPath method I do the following where xLabel is the UILabel sub view in the pushed view controller's xib:

```
self.detailViewController.xLabel.text = [[[xArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"xDesc"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

What do I need to do to have the data appear the first time a row is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood you correctly, there is no xLabel object the first time around as it will be created when the UIViewController is being "loaded". So, when you try to set the text value, it isnt loaded into the label, as there is no label. Subsequent attempts work as the label is created from the first attempt. Anyways, if you need to share some data with the detail view, store then in a dictionary or some other object rather than just assigning it directly to the view from the current controller.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I guess where I am getting lost is that I create and load up the dictionary in the table view controller as:    self.xArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"xDict" ofType:@"plist"]]; and then load up the table, and when the row is selected I have the index path that identifies the appropriate elements in the array.  So, how do I share the array "with the detail view"?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not working because first time when you select a row your detail view controller is not there in memory stack, so you can not call setText method of a label in previous view controller. Second time its working because its there in memory so you can call set method to its component. What i want to say it that when you are pushing detail view controller in stack just set a string of detail view controller here (this string should be property of detail view controller) and then in detail view controller's viewDidLoad method set the text of your label to this string.

Comment: The xLabel string is declared as a property in the detail view controller.  I've tried `xLabel.text = [[[xIndexViewController.xArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"xLabel"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` in the detail view controller's viewDidLoad but this gives the error "use of undeclared identifier 'indexPath'.  I've declare the xIndexViewController as an ivar and synthesized in the detail view controller. I understand that the setText assignment should be done in the detail view controller but still am not getting how to "share the table data in the detail controller.

Comment: Also don't understand why the detail controller is not in memory as I lazily instantiate it via: `if (self.xDetailViewController == nil) {
        XDetailViewController *tempDetailController = [[XDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        self.cloudInstanceViewController = tempDetailController;
        [tempDetailController release];` in the table controller's didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I solved this after poking around on the board here and found [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472824/modal-view-controller-displays-blank-first-time-works-properly-subsequently) which let me to put the property assignments **after** the pushViewController instruction in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. My table data now loads the first time the row is selected. Thanks all.